# A single action for any route in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

Is it possible to make one action for every possible route (unlimited amount of routes) of a Rails app?

```
http://myapp.com/
http://myapp.com/a
http://myapp.com/b/c
http://myapp.com/whatever/i/enter/here
```

should lead to one action.

Comment: why do you want to do this? I cannot see a useful case to implement such behavior

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this.

```
get '*path' => "controller_name#action"
```

Similarly you can do for post. Keep it at the top of the file.

> Update

You can do this for all http methods.

```
match '*path', to: 'controller_name#action', via: :all
```

Should do the trick. Write your methods accordingly to handle to different kinds of request.